# Maintaining a big list of properies in a class that can be exported as a csv row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and trying to store a list of data in CSV format.

I've got a wrapper class for the csv and for each row I have a `DataRow`. However, I know this code isn't very maintainable.

Currently, if I want to add a new value I need to add a condition in the `set_item` add a new field in `fields` and a new property in the class.

Is there a better solution to maintaining a list of properties in a class?

Ideally my `DataRow` class would just have a list of `fields` with some generic methods.

```py
class DataRow:
  
  # These are used as the column headings in the csv. 
  # They are just the accessible keys.
  fields: List[str] = ['id', 'name', 'created', 'time']

  # I still want to reference specific values so I add them to class
  # I have so many properties I don't really want to list them all here.
  id:str
  name:str
  created: str
  time: str
  
  def __init__(self) -> None:

  def get_labels(self) -> List[str]:
    return self.fields
  
  # reference is a string from external source so need to map it to a property
  def set_item(self, reference:str, value:str):
    # in this case reference doesn't match up with the property name
    if reference == 'my id':
      self.id = value
    if reference == 'item name':
      self.name = value
    if reference == 'date':
      self.created = value
    if reference == 'time':
      self.time = value
   
   def get_item(self, key:str):
      # I want to get the property based on field self[name]
    

class DataFile:
    name: str
    rows: List[DataRow] = []

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
    
    def open(self):
       # will open the csv file and set the rows

    def save(self):
       # will save the latest rows to csv file
    
    def add_row(id: str, row:DataRow ):
       self.rows.append(row)
```

Comment: Maybe instead of `fields` you can try something like `DataRow.__annotations__.keys()`? That'll remove one of the places you need to change.

Comment: Or, you can make `fields` a `dict` of the "reference" to the attribute name in the class so that in `set_item` you can do `setattr(self, self.fields[reference], value)`

Comment: @david I think that's what I'm aiming to do, but not how sure to implement it. Coud you provide an example?

Comment: I posted an answer below that implements what I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make `fields` a `dict` from the property name on the class to the reference name. This way you can store everything in one place.

```py
class DataRow:
    fields = {'id': 'my id', 'name': 'item name', 'created': 'date', 'time': 'time'}
    # _ref_to_field[reference] = field_name
    _ref_to_field = {v: k for k, v in fields.items()}
    # used to save some memory because __dict__ is not needed
    __slots__ = tuple(fields.keys())

    def get_labels(self) -> list[str]:
        return list(self.fields)
    
    def set_item(self, reference:str, value:str):
        setattr(self, self._ref_to_field[reference], value)
    
    def get_item(self, key:str):
        return getattr(self, key)

# testing the DataRow class
row = DataRow()
row.set_item('my id', '12345')
row.set_item('item name', 'foo bar')
row.set_item('date', '1970-01-01')
row.set_item('time', '00:00:00')
for field in row.get_labels():
    print(field, row.get_item(field))
```

This prints:

```
id 12345
name foo bar
created 1970-01-01
time 00:00:00
```

Now, you only need to specify the fields and their corresponding `reference` values in the `fields` class variable.

Comment: Thanks David. This is exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: One question. Is there a way to restrict the arguments of `get_item` to be key in `fields` Ie. `keyof fields`. I'm from a Typescript background so maybe I'm thinking of types too much.

Comment: Oh you mean static type checking? Unfortunately I think no... I don't think there's a `keyof` equivalent in python :-( At runtime you can just check `if key not in self.fields:` and raise an error or something.